# Socket IO server restart causes duplicate client emits

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When I make changes to my Node/Socket IO server and restart it, the connected client will start emitting two messages for each one. If I restart again, it will start emitting three, and so forth.

The only "fix" I see is to refresh the page on client to force a new connection.

**How do I prevent the client from emitting multiple messages after a server restart?**

Pretty standard setup:

**Server**

```
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => l(`Server started on port ${port}`));
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile('/public/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

io.on('connection', client => client.on('event', (msg) => console.log(msg));
```

**Client**

```
const socket = io.connect('', { query: { path: window.location.pathname }, reconnect: false, forceNew: true });

$("body").on("click", "a", () => socket.emit('event', 'test'));
```

Comment: Please share some code you use so we can help you on it.

Comment: Added code. Pretty standard setup...

Comment: Did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/430#issuecomment-451130988

Don't wrap the socket.on in actions like connect or authenticated.

In my example I had a "socket.on" wrapped in authorization. As soon as the client reconnected the socket.on stacked up and multiplied each time the server restarted.